# Is the 'local' vm required once the swarm cluster has been deployed?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-swarm, swarm

According to the official documentation on [Install and Create a Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/), first step is to create a vm named *local* which is needed to obtain the token with `swarm create`.

Once the manager and all nodes have been created and added to the swarm cluster, do I need to keep running the *local* vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: this tutorial is for the *first version* of Swarm (called `Swarm legacy`). There is a new version called `Swarm mode` available since Docker `1.12`. Putting it out there because there seems to be a lot of confusion between the two.

No you don't have to keep the `local` VM, this is just to get a unique cluster token with the *Docker Hub* discovery service.

Now this is a bit overkill just to generate a token. You can bypass this step by:

- Running the swarm container directly if you have `Docker for Mac` or a more generally a local instance of Docker running:

  ```
  docker run --rm swarm create
  ```
- Directly query the service discovery URL to generate a token:

  ```
  curl -X POST "https://discovery.hub.docker.com/v1/clusters"
  ```